# How to make the output shows tabs instead of showing \t?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user for number of elements then input these elements, then bubbles sort them.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp


ntimes = raw_input("Enter the number of lines \n")

ntimes = int(ntimes)

alist = []

while (ntimes > 0):
    ntimes -= 1
    alist.append(raw_input('Enter the list to sort \n'))
bubbleSort(alist)
print (alist)
```

My code works fine except that if the input includes a tab, the output gives `\t` instead. How to make my code to show tabs? And how to make the output shows each value in a separate line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the list as separate elements by joining them with newlines:

```
print '\n'.join(alist)
```

or, if you are using the `print()` *function* (Python 3, or after using `from __future__ import print_function`), by passing them in as separate arguments to `print()`:

```
print(*alist, sep='\n')
```

The `*` in front of `alist` tells Python to separate out the values in the list and apply them as separate arguments, as if you called `print(alist[0], alist[1], ..., alist[n])`. The `sep` argument tells Python to use newlines between the arguments.

As this prints each argument separately, `print()` uses `str()` on each instead of letting the list representation use `repr()` on each.

Demo:

```
>>> alist = ['\tfirst with tab', 'second item', 'third\titem\twith\ttabs']
>>> print alist
['\tfirst with tab', 'second item', 'third\titem\twith\ttabs']
>>> print '\n'.join(alist)
    first with tab
second item
third   item    with    tabs
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*alist, sep='\n')
    first with tab
second item
third   item    with    tabs
```

Comment: @user3467152: add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file; you are using Python 2.

Comment: @user3467152: updated to give you more Python 2 options.

Comment: thanks, "print '\n'.join(alist)" fixes the output and shows tabs. Well, i don't even know which version I'm using because I'm using the school server and I've never used python before

Comment: It's Python 2; `raw_input()` would not be available otherwise.